# Multiple Data Tables in PHP/MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, dataset

In asp.net, you can retrieve MULTIPLE datatables from a single call to the database.  Can you do the same thing in php?

Example:

```
$sql ="select * from t1; select * from t2;";
$result = SomeQueryFunc($sql);
print_r($result[0]); // dump results for t1
print_r($result[1]); // dump results for t2
```

Can you do something like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called "multi-query."  The mysql extension in PHP does not have any means to enable multi-query.  The mysqli extension does allow you to use multi-query, but only through the multi_query() method.  See http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php

Using multi-query is not recommended, because it can increase the potential damage caused by SQL injection attacks.  If you use multi-query, you should use rigorous code inspection habits to avoid SQL injection vulnerability.

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible with newer MySQL and the mysqli (improved) php extension.
I'm not sure if any DB abstraction layers support this.

See relevant [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/c-api-multiple-queries.html) and 
[PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php).

Answer (score 0):

[`PDOStatement::nextRowset()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.nextrowset.php) seems to be what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using classic MySQL, you can't. You can create a function which will look like

```
function SomeQueryFunc($queries) {
    $queries = explode(';', $queries);
    $return = array();
    foreach($queries as $index => $query) {
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        $return[$index] = array();
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
           foreach($row as $column => $value) {
              $return[$index][$column] = $value;
           }
        }
    }
    return $return;
}
```

which will work as expected