# Can a query be made as an array wherein multiple tables are checked for desired values?

Tags: php, mysql

Can I write a query in MYSQL (eventually for PHP + MySQL) such that I can check across multiple tables in a sort of array?

***For example***
Suppose I have tables **client**, **car**, **rate**
Each table has an ID.

In **client** are rows ... ID, Name, address
In **car** are rows ... ID, Make, Model, Year, License plate number
In **rate** are rows ... ID, 1-day, 2-day, 3-day

would the following work?:

```
SELECT name, make, model, license plate number, 1-day FROM client, car, rate WHERE make = ford
```

or in PHP

```
$q = "SELECT name, make, model, license plate number, 1-day FROM client, car, rate WHERE make = ford";
```

would this be correct syntax?

Comment: I'm confused as to what you want to achieve here... There doesn't seem to be anyway of linking these tables together..?

Comment: You need to chagne your DB structre so those tables will have `relations`.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can´t. Not the way you are presenting it here. What you can do is JOINS if the tables are related to each other. Otherwise you´d probably have to select from one table at the time.

[You may also implement an iterative solution in PHP to return from several tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198650/multiple-data-tables-in-php-mysql) or consider doing it on the database side with a stored procedure.

Normally when using a relational database there are relations between the tables so that you may perform join operations on them as such (a very loose example since I do not know anything about the context in which you are working):

```
SELECT c.name, c.make, c.model, c.licensePlateNumber FROM car AS c JOIN client AS cl ON c.ClientId = cl.ClientId JOIN rate AS r ON cl.RateId = r.RateId WHERE c.make = 'Ford';
```

Related: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1683794/retrieving-multiple-result-sets-with-stored-procedure-in-php-mysqli)

Comment: Thank you.  As the first respondent above mentioned a joins is the preferred method for best results.

Answer (score 1):

yes you can do that you send your table names as array and id to you query function
then do as shown below

```
function multiple_table_query($tbl_ary,$id)
{
      foreach($tbl_ary as $tbl)
{
    $sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl where id=$id"
    $result[]=mysql_fetch_array($sql)
}
}
 return $result;
```

but this is not preffered method better to go for sql joins to get accurate and good looking results.

Comment: Thank you.  Both this and the method below seem to work.  You answer, however, has the PHP code needed and is more concise.  (And is perhaps more elegant - not that it really matters; I just like it).